# How the client can know when the server send a message?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I will try to express it as good as a can. I need to create an online chat but NOT a group chat, but a private one.I mean i need a server where a lot of client can connect and each one of them can send a message to another client(if he knows his IP or Username). If the receiver is offline he will receive the message when he will connect to the serve(the easy part). If he is online he could do 2 jobs:

1.Send message to another client
2.Receive a message from another client.

My problem is how to interupt the sending process and tell the client that he has a new unread message?

I am looking up to use the SIGIO signal,but i am really not familiar.Am i in the right way?

PS:The server is running in an embedded system.

Comment: When the client "writes" to the server, the server has the ability to "respond" right?
So when you connect, the only way for the server to know you are "there" is to send a message. Then the server will reply saying "Hey bro! by the way, you've mail!"

Comment: Yeah thats a cool and easy way to solve it.My mind had been stuck.Thanks a lot!!!!
If anyone knows a more expert way to do it i would love to hear it.

Comment: As a note, this would be easier to implement with a language other than C which has zero knowledge of things like Unicode characters and has very primitive string processing capabilities. C++ would be a huge step up.

Comment: Normally clients listen on their sockets for data using something like `select` or equivalent (e.g. epoll/kqueue). If you need something to help wrap that and you really want to commit to C, consider using [libuv](http://libuv.org) as a foundation.